# problem in the textfields in iphone sdk

Tags: objective-c, uitextfield

I am having two textfields in which if enter the text more than 100 characters I need to display the alert only when I tap onto the second textfield.Can any one suggest me how to do this.

Thanks to all,
Monish.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create two UITextFields, and set their tag properties to 1 and 2 respectively. Next, implement the `UITextFieldDelegate` protocol in your header file, like so;

```
@interface MyViewController : UIViewController <UITextFieldDelegate> {
}
```

And then in your implementation file, use the textFieldDidBeginEditing delegate method to check the length and display alert messages. E.g

```
- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField {
if (textField.tag == 2 && [self.myfirstTextField.text length] > 100) {
       //-- display the alert message
    }
}
```